# 508 Resource Limit Is Reached

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I rent dedicated server for share hosting.
Many of my client using big resource so i want to limited user account for using the CPU usage, RAM usage or the number of concurrent processes.

I saw in a number of hosting service providers, displays the error message like this if a user account exceed the capacity, the error message will appear like this:

**508 Resource Limit Is Reached.**
*The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.*

How can i do that??

**Note:**

- I'm using centos 5.3
- Apache webserver

Forgive me, if my english language not good.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit resources such as cpu per cpanel account, you will need to get a different operating system called [CloudLinux](http://cloudlinux.com/). CloudLinux OS is made to serve this exact purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much you give me the information about CloudLinux. But it is posible to limited resource using php.ini or others centos module?

Comment: If i change my question, do you know the mods or plugin in centos display this error: "**508 Resource Limit Is Reached. The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later**" ???

Comment: Then the answer is no. It is not possible. It's possible to limit per process, but that's not per account.

Comment: May i know how to limit per process?? Thank you so much Peter for your help.

Comment: Multiple ways, unfit for comment. But it will NOT achieve what you want of displaying that 508 message. cloudlinux is the **only** way to get you that 508 message per account.